# Вывод имени незаполненого поля

Tags: css3, jquery, ajax, javascript

Добрый вечер.

Такая проблема появилась. Если, допустим, так прописать:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contact">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span></span>
    </p>
</form>
```

то js:

```
$('#contact').submit(function(){
        var errors = false;
        $(this).find('div').empty();

        $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
            if( $.trim( $(this).val() ) == '' ) {
                errors = true;
                $(this).next().text( 'Не заполнено поле ' + $(this).prev().text() );
            }
        });

        if( !errors ){
            var data = $('#contact').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#submit').next().text('Отправляю...');
                },
                success: function(res){
                    if( res == 1 ){
                        $('#contact').find('input:not(#submit), textarea').val('');
                        $('#submit').next().empty();
                        alert('Письмо отправлено');
                    }else{
                        $('#submit').next().empty();
                        alert('Ошибка отправки');
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Ошибка!');

            }
        });
          }
 }
```

выводит имя поля, если его не заполнишь, а если так:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contact">
<tr>        
        <td>Введите ваше имя <strong style="color:red;">*</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <div class="formaobr"></div></td>
    </tr>
       </form>
```

то ошибка без имени, то есть - 'Не заполнено поле'.

Что здесь не так?

**Обновление**

На сайте том выходит ошибка, когда нажимаю отправить у формы. В общем, нужно так: когда поля не заполнены, писало Не заполнено поле Имя... и т.д., а сейчас скрипт выдает только - Не заполнено поле, а какое именно, не указывает. Для такой формы нужно:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contact">
<tr>        
        <td>Введите ваше имя <strong style="color:red;">*</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <div class="formaobr"></div></td>
    </tr>
       </form>
```

Comment: Кто что знает, как исправить, очень нужно))

Comment: По вашему объяснению и вопросу "Что здесь не так?" совсем не понятна ваша проблема, а чтобы ещё лучше понять сделайте пример на jsfiddle.net, может у вас проблема в php, который здесь не присутствует

Comment: @MasterAlex,
На сайте том выходит ошибка, когда нажимаю отправить у формы. Вообщем нужно так: когда поля не заполнены, писало Не заполнено поле Имя... и т.д, а сейчас скрипт выдает только - Не заполнено поле, а какое именно не указывает. Код формы:
<form action="" method="post" id="contact">
<tr>        
        <td>Введите ваше имя <strong style="color:red;">*</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <div class="formaobr"></div></td>
    </tr>
       </form>

Comment: Текст о незаполненном поле может выходить под каждым полем, если они не заполнены.

Comment: Кто поможет?